# How to Enable AccessExternalSchema for camel core xml parser

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-core

Found in https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_21.html that access to external schema for xml parser was disabled for camel-core.

I'm currently experiencing this error in camel route start up :
`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'so.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.`

which I'm pretty confident now is caused by this disablement because the routes in question are configured through spring xml. Does anyone know of any workarounds to reenable this?

*Side note* not able to share any of the code specifics due to company restrictions. I understand that this will make responses general. will answer any questions that I can.

Currently, tried rewriting spring xml route configuration to Java DSL and the problem was fixed. However ideally would hope not to do this because spring xml file is about 400 lines long and rewriting would take a significant amount of time. any and all answers/respones are appreciated!